# Is Monster Kid's sister older or younger?

Tags: undertale

Monster Kid refers to a "sister" once or twice in dialog, notably at 1:03 of this cutscene:

In Japanese, there are separate words for "older sister" and "younger sister," so I assume the Japanese localization had to pick one. Unfortunately, I do not speak Japanese. Which did they use?

Note that I am specifically looking for an answer based on the *official Japanese localization.* I am aware that the linked YouTube video contains Chinese(!) characters, but those characters are not relevant to this question because they are not official.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official Japanese translation uses **ねえちゃん (*nee-chan*, older sister)**.

> ※ そんなの　**ねえちゃん**に
>   　まいにち　いわれてっぞ！